# Restrict orientation for ceritain size classes

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, size-classes

I am trying to restrict the orientation for the regular-width, compact-height, compact-with, compact-height i.e. iPhone landscape mode, to portrait.

The main thing I am wondering is whether this is possible through the interface builder or its is an event I have to catch in code during the viewController lifecycle, disabling portrait all together is not an option as I want the app to support multitasking.

The youtube app is a good example of this, where they have restricted iphone orientation to portrait but supported it for iPad and multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the project settings -> General

You will see that you can specify the supported orientation per device

[image: Orientation per device]

Or, to do this programmatically for a universal app:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i tried this it did not work as i needed  the devices to be universal i.e. by this method yiou are stating that the app is meant for iPads only, see below for my answer

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, for those that don't know :

1. In your top project file, set devices to universal, select all orientations.
2. Go to your info.plist file and find : Supported interface orientations (you will see two of these, choose the one that does not say iPad next to it)
3. Disable any orientations you do not want to support for the iPhone.

I am assuming that as long as you support portrait mode for iPhones you will no conflict with multitasking settings, as you are support all the necessary size classes.